# Preventing certain words in a text box

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Im trying to prevent certain words beings entered in a text box using js on my wordpress store. I am using the shopkeeper theme.

I started by creating a file in the root of my site called avoidtext.js and entered the following code shown in this snippet:

```js
var banned = ['MMM','XXX'];
document.getElementById('field_1_17').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById('field_1_17').value;
    for (var x=0;x<banned.length;x++) {
        if (text.search(banned[x]) !== -1) {
            alert(banned[x]+' is not allowed!');
        }
        var regExp = new RegExp(banned[x]);
        text = text.replace(regExp,'');
    }
    document.getElementById('field_1_17').value = text;
},false);
```

```html
<input id="field_1_17" />
```

I then went to my main function file and at the bottom entered:

```java
function enqueue_my_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'avoidtext', 'https://reubenstore.com/avoidtext.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_custom_script' );
```

this does nothing. I have viewed the page source and the avoidtext script is there. thank you.

Comment: sorry about this and thanks!

Comment: Check your browser's console log. Are you seeing any warning/error message(s) that might be related to your script?

Comment: @cabrerahector yes there is. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at avoidtext.js?ver=5.2.3:2

Comment: ok so from what I've read its basically because the element it's looking for has not loaded in when the script is executed. I'm just wondering would the fact the element is hidden until a certain selection on the page is made affect this?

Comment: Please have a look at the answer below and [consider marking as as accepted if it helped](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your script is being executed before the browser has had the chance to completely parse the DOM. According to your code, your JS file is being injected into the `<head>` section of your website, and your element is somewhere far down below inside the `<body>` tag. So, to your script, your `field_1_17` element doesn't exist, hence it fails to add your event listener function.

Two ways to fix this:

**Option 1. Have your script injected into the footer section of your site instead:**

```
function enqueue_my_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'avoidtext', // slug
        'https://reubenstore.com/avoidtext.js', // path to script
        array(), // dependencies
        true // wether to place the script in the head section (false) or in the footer section (true)
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_custom_script' );
```

This way by the time your script is read by the browser your element has already been parsed by it, making it available to your script.

**Option 2. Have your script run after the DOM is ready for manipulation:**

Use the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event to trigger your script once the browser has fully parsed the HTML of your website:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    var banned = ['MMM','XXX'];
    document.getElementById('field_1_17').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        var text = document.getElementById('field_1_17').value;
        for (var x=0;x<banned.length;x++) {
            if (text.search(banned[x]) !== -1) {
                alert(banned[x]+' is not allowed!');
            }
            var regExp = new RegExp(banned[x]);
            text = text.replace(regExp,'');
        }
        document.getElementById('field_1_17').value = text;
    }, false);

});
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. now i am getting the error : Uncaught TypeError: text.search is not a function at HTMLLIElement. Any idea's here.

Comment: The `search()` function can only be used on strings. It seems you're trying to use it on an `LI` element (or at least that's what the error is saying) which is why you're getting that error. I'm assuming you must have changed something in your code?